# Buffer output issue QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, buffer

I'm using QGIS 3.18 version. I tried to use the buffer tool with the centerline (provided for a sample) of the road.

[image]

I found overlapping of buffer polygons and some unusual shapes of polygons too. I tried all the possible ways to identify it. In another step, I tried to do the same process on my own shapefile and which run properly. How can I get out of this situation?

Comment: It's possible you have double vertices nearly coincident, try repairing your geometries and see if that helps. This post might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/391094/how-to-use-v-clean-in-qgis-to-fix-polygon-topology

Comment: Agree with Michael Stimson. Also try round end cap style.