# Point Sampling Tool

Tags: qgis

I am trying to use the Point Sampling tool in QGIS however once completed the values come up as NULL in the attribute table. I have already made sure that all layers are in the same CRS as I have read this is the common cause, anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps your polygon or point geometries have bad geometries in them... if they've come from CAD that's almost a given. Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/391094/how-to-use-v-clean-in-qgis-to-fix-polygon-topology which highligts several ways to validate/clean your geometries.